# Java: Scanner not accepting try-catch class error when reading from file

Tags: java, file, exception, try-catch, java.util.scanner

At Java 8 documentation, it is written that the constructor from Scanner which receives a File Source as parameter throws a `FileNotFoundException`.
But take a look at the following code:

```
  try{
            sc = new Scanner("Rede.txt");      //This archive already exists
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException f){
            f.printStackTrace;
        }
        finally{
            sc.close();
        }
```

When I run it, I get something like:

```
error:exception FileNotFoundException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
              catch(FileNotFoundException f){
```

Same happens with `IOException`. The curious is that, if I throw away the try-catch part, the code compiles.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scanner can also scan a String. To see what I mean, try:

```
System.out.println( new Scanner("Rede.txt").next() );
```

It will print `Rede.txt`.

Some other classes (like e.g. FileInputStream) will take a String path, but Scanner doesn't. If you want to use a file, you need to actually pass it a File:

```
sc = new Scanner(new File("Rede.txt"));
```